# Transaction Error on Creating a Smart Contract with a deployed Smart Contract in Web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-contract

I am trying to create a Contr smart contract object with deployed SystemAPI contract, but I get a transaction revert error upon calling it.

SystemAPI contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "./Contr.sol";

contract SystemAPI{


    function createContr() public returns (address) {
        Contr c = new Contr("one two");
        // return address(c);
        return address(c);
        // return "Hello World";
    }

    function signContract(address addr) public {
        Contr c = Contr(addr);
        c.sign(msg.sender);
    }

    function checkSigned(address addr) public returns(bool) {
        Contr c = Contr(addr);
        return c.checkSigned(msg.sender);
    }

    // function getContractData(address addr) public returns(string memory) {
    //     Contr c = Contr(addr);
    //     return c.getData();
    // }
}
```

Contr Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Contr{
    string data;
    mapping(address => bool) public people;

    constructor(string memory _data) public {
        data = _data;
    }

    function sign(address person) public returns(bool) {
        people[person] = true;
        return people[person];
    }

    function checkSigned(address addr) public view returns(bool) {
        return people[addr];
    }

    function getData() public view returns(string memory){
        return data;
    }
}
```

Web3 Contract Call Code:

```
  // const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(StorageContract.abi, deployedNetwork2.address);
  const result = contract.methods.createContr().send({
    from: '0x1a17e768f1ecbf31c44d60cb845242a0a89f4993'
  }).on('error', 
    function(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  ).on('receipt', function(receipt){
    console.log("done");
  });
```

Error Log:

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on remix, there everything works as expected.

Comment: Yes, in remix its working as expected but when I try to integrate it on web3 , it shows some unexpected error

Comment: On what network did you deploy this? Could you share the address?

Comment: Actually Its on my local truffle network for testing purpose